# Jdbc Java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

Below is the part of code from my jsp page, when I am printing the rs.getString(1)is printing perfectly but as soon as i put the rs.getString(1) in if  block it shows the null pointer exception. Please help

```
String nam=request.getParameter("n");
String query = "select name from ques where username='"+userid+"'";

Statement st=con.prepareStatement(query);

ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);


while(rs.next()){

    out.println(rs.getString(1));

    if(rs.getString(1).equals(nam)){

        out.print("hello");

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean if block or the while block?

Comment: The problem may be because of "nam" value. Can you try to print nam value?

Comment: Be careful! This code, as written, is a SQL Injection Attack waiting to happen. Read more at http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I mean if block, yes i have printed nam value and it is accessible over there, the exception occurs if i put rs.getString in if() block